# Passing variable from batch file to SSIS package

Tags: ssis, batch-file

I have created a package which takes a variable from batch file and uses it for execution.

I am sending it from batch file as:

Exit %Output%

And set Output of Execute processTask but not being able to access it further.

Please help.!

Comment: It's difficult to understand what your problem is. You'll have to explain your problem a little better. How do you invoke your bat file. Exit is a command to quit the execution of the current cmd, is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you should **echo** the variable %Output% instead of using with **Exit** command.

Following example shows how to pass a string from batch file to SSIS:

1. Screenshot #**1** shows the contents of the batch file used in this example.
2. Screenshot #**2** shows the *Execute Process Task* configuration. The variable **BatchOutput** is of type string.
3. Screenshot #**3** shows that the *Script Task* `Success` is added after the batch Execute Process Task.
4. In the Script Task, I have the code shown under the **Script Task code** section to display the contents of the variable **BatchOutput**.
5. Execution of the task should show the contents of the variable, which is actually the text echoed from the batch file. refer screenshot #**4**.

**Script Task code:** *(Use the code given below to replace the Main() method in your Script task)*

**VB** Main() method code that can be used in **`SSIS 2005 and above`**

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim varCollection As Variables = Nothing    

    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::BatchOutput")
    Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(varCollection)

    MessageBox.Show(varCollection("User::BatchOutput").Value.ToString())

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

**C#** Main() method code that can be used only in **`SSIS 2008 and above`**
.

```
public void Main()
{
    Variables varCollection = null;
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::BatchOutput");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);

    MessageBox.Show(varCollection["User::BatchOutput"].Value.ToString());
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

Comment: I am being unable to execute another batch file through same code... 
Can u find out error in batch file???
Batch file is:



@echo OFF

dtexec /f "D:\CHORD_LOAD_PACKAGE\CHORD_LOAD_PACKAGE\

LOAD_SECURITY.dtsx" /REPORTING E> D:\Loagfile.log 


if %ERRORLEVEL%==1 set %OUTPUT%="S"
if %ERRORLEVEL%!=1 set %OUTPUT%="F"

echo "EXCEL"
exit 0

Comment: There is no any error message Siva,
It just passing a blank string to SSIS package after execution.
I made few needed changes in batch file as shown above...