# Passing A Variable From Batch Script To SSIS as a stored value

Tags: batch-file, ssis

In a ssis package I have a batch script that connects to winscp to check if a file exist or it doesn't.

If it exists it gets value 0, if it doesn't exist it gets value 1.

I want to have that value stored into a variable which is created from ssis.

I am running the batch script through ssis via execute process task and the StandardOutputVariable holds the variable called fileexist which is a string variable.

But the problem is that its not storing the value into the variable for me to use in ssis.

The goal is to use that value that is stored in the variable to add a function to precedence constraint editor where if the value is 0 it goes to the right side of code and if the value is 1 it goes to the left side of the code.

Please let me know where I went wrong in the code.

Batch Script:

```
    @echo off
 
set REMOTE_PATH=/D:/TRANSFERS/IN/FILE.TXT
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\"
WinSCP.com /command ^
    "open ftptwo" ^
    "stat %REMOTE_PATH%" ^
    "exit"
 
if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error
set fileexist = 0
exit /b 0
 
:error
set fileexist = 1
exit /b 1
```

Comment: First things first, there is no such location in the root of the drive of the current working directory, `/` as `D:/TRANSFERS/IN/FILE.TXT`. For example, if your current working directory is `C:\Users\Junsh` then you're effectively using `C:/D:/TRANSFERS/IN/FILE.TXT`, and if your current working directory is `D:\TestDir`, you'd effectively be using `D:/D:/TRANSFERS/IN/FILE.TXT`. You should therefore be using `Set "REMOTE_PATH=D:/TRANSFERS/IN/FILE.TXT"`. Next, `set fileexist = 0` and `set fileexist = 1` are using the wrong syntax. They should read `Set "fileexist=0"` and `Set "fileexist=1"`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing variable from batch file to SSIS package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135520/passing-variable-from-batch-file-to-ssis-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the lines where you're setting fileexist to just echo the value. That will write the value to the standard output, which is what the SSIS Execute Process Task is capturing in the StandardOutputVariable.

```
@echo off

set REMOTE_PATH=/D:/TRANSFERS/IN/FILE.TXT
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\"
WinSCP.com /command ^
    "open ftptwo" ^
    "stat %REMOTE_PATH%" ^
    "exit"


if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error
echo 0
exit /b 0

:error
echo 1
exit /b 1
```

Once the batch file has been executed, the SSIS variable fileexist should hold the value 0 or 1 as a string. You can use this variable in a precedence constraint expression to direct the flow of your package. In the precedence constraint editor, use the expression @[User::fileexist] == "0" or @[User::fileexist] == "1" as needed.

Comment: Simple `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` would suffice.

Comment: I saw why it didn't work. It's because for some reason even if I wanted to just read the echo value alone. The output of the batch file also brings out the winscp ftp login and stores all of that information into the variable. 

Do you happen to know if there is any way for that winscp ftp login info to not appear in the output from running the batch?

Comment: Just redirect it to nul: `> nul`